# How to get the previous value of a node in firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am sending a request to the firebase client SDK (JavaScript) which sends to the location of a vehicle in realtime..I get the following object

```
​{
  "bearing": 264.8562316894531,
  "latitude": "19.9742249",
  "longitude": "73.7910482",
  "timestamp": "1582103153697",
  "trip": "40be478c-b0b0-41fb-bc70-66b2507719ef",
  "user": "1985"
}
```

I want to be able to get the value before it changes so I can calculate the angle to rotate my marker(HEADING).

any help is appreciated

Comment: How are you calling this "Firebase API"? Through a Client SDK? Through the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start)?

Comment: Through firebase client SDK.. more specifically the `firebase` npm package

Answer (score 0):

By using one of the Firebase Client SDKs there is no out-of-the-box way to get the previous value of a given Realtime Database node when you write a new value to this node.

You will need to **first read the node**, by querying the database (in your case, I guess through a vehicle Id or a user Id), "storing" this value in your front end and **then write the new value** of the node to the Realtime Database.

You haven't given any detail on which kind of client/app you are developing for (Web? Android? iOS?) so it is impossible to give you more detail on how to implement this workflow/sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `bearing` enough for you to rotate your marker? Something like

```
marker.rotate(newData.bearing - marker.bearing);
```